# How to validate a form's input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I am trying to validate a form's input value after clicking a button using jQuery and javascript.

Right now, if I put in a value for the input and click submit the input field and button just disappears.  Any idea what I have wrong here?

The HTML file...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id='input_1'>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" id="send">
            </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

The script file...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.send').click(function() {
        validateInput(document.getElementById('#input_1'));
        function validateInput(inputValue){
             if (inputValue === 3) {
             alert("Element cannot be equal to 3");
             }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: [Best jQuery Form Plugin. Easily validate anything useing "beforeSubmit" option](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm)

Comment: `click(function(event) { event.preventDefault();` will stop executing form submit

Comment: Additional do not use `click()`. Please use `on('click',...`

Comment: First is you do not prevent it will send request, second is more semantic.

Comment: You are right, but most programmers I know and discuss this problem prefer `on`. Only because this is more readable than `$('button').click` for example.

Comment: @Eraden It's not really necessary. After all `.click(function(e) {` and `.on("click", function(e) {` are synonymous. What would be different would be if he wanted to use the `delegate` version for `dynamic` input, such as `$("#container").on("click", ".new-elm-classname", function(e) {`

Comment: @Eraden eh, tomato, tomato. I've known many over the last several years that would argue for and many against that. At the end of the day it's coders preference. I've worked contracts from Doctors to US Army, and none of them cared what my work "looked like", only that it was done. LoL. I think he should know it's just a coding preference. -My opinion.

Comment: Yes, but after several months other programmers may be angry because you leave something that is hard to read. End-user is always not interested how you wrote something but your co-programmers always

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send').live('click',function() { //Because send is the id of your button
        if(validateInput(document.getElementById('#input_1'))){
            alert("Element cannot be equal to 3");
            return false;
         }
         else{
             //Do something else
         }
        function validateInput(inputValue){
             if (inputValue == 3) {
             return false;//Will prevent further actions
             }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I see I was using . instead of # for the send button.  I also included the 'return false;//Will prevent further actions' as you recommended.  The input and button are still disappearing after hitting send.  Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Use `.on()` or `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`. Live is deprecated!

Comment: The return false must be inside the click function, not `validateInput()`.

Comment: Or call `validateInput` like that : `return validateInput(arg)` and keep your return false in the function.

Comment: This prevented the input and button from disappearing but if I enter 3 the alert isn't executing.

Answer (score 0):

1. this `$('.send').click(function() {`
   should be `$("#send").click(function() {`.
   Notice the Hash symbol and not the dot (.), dot is used if the selector is a class whereas the # is used if the selector is an ID.

2.You should move the validation function outside the  `$(document).ready(function()`.. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses.  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it to work using your recommendations.  I decided to use jQuery to get the element and appended a message to a div instead of using alert.  This was a different approach but ended up working.

HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="input"/>

            </form>
            <button id="send">Send</button>
            <div class="error">
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send').click(function(){ 
    var toValidate = $('input[name=input]').val();
    if (toValidate == 3) {
    jQuery('.message').html('');
        $('.error').append('<div class="message">' + toValidate + " is    invalid" + '</div>');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.message').html('');
        $('.error').append('<div class="message">' + toValidate + " is valid" + '</div>');
         }

    });
});
```